# An efficient way to deserialize the same json stream twice by Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json that I receive in a System.IO.StreamReader. Its structure is as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Property1": "Value1",
            "Property2": "Value2"
        },
        {
            "Property1": "Value3",
            "Property2": "Value4"
        }
    ],
    "metaData": {
        (some other structure)
    }
}
```

And I have two classes, one that has `Property1` as a data field, and another one that has `Property2` as a data field.

I would like to use the incoming stream to deserialize this json into two separate collections of the two classes that I have.

So far, I managed to do this only by stringifying the stream first and then invoking `DeserliazeObject(string)` twice. But then a huge chunk of memory is allocated unnecessarily.

How can I do this by means of a single invocation to `DeserializeObject(streamReader)`? Does Newtonsoft expose any serialization settings that can help me with this?

This is the code that I have, which is inefficient because I convert the stream to a string before invoking the deserializer:

```cs
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
var records = GetRecords(jObject);

private IList<(IClass1, IClass2)> GetRecords(JObject jObject)
{
  return jObject["data"]
    .Children()
    .Select(CreateRecord)
    .ToList();
}

private (Class1, Class2) CreateRecord(JToken recordToken)
{
  var object1 = recordToken.ToObject<IClass1>();
  var object2 = recordToken.ToObject<IClass2>();
  return (object1, object2);
}
```

Comment: Why not just copy the collection after you deserialize once?

Comment: Can you share the class structures and the code you have written for deserialization?

Comment: Having `string` will only save from loading json-file. But deserialization will still occurs (e.g. parsing values from string). You say *efficient* and then *memory*, why do you introduce `string` at all? There are methods exists to deserialize directly from the file/stream. Deserializing twice may be efficient in certain scenarios, we have no idea about yours.

Comment: Create a type that has both properties (or use a dynamic type), deserialize to that, then use LINQ to create the types you need.

Comment: @Sinatr It appears the OP knows about `DeserializeObject(StreamReader)`, as they mention it in the last paragraph as a desirable use case. They're using `string` only because it's the only way they know of reusing the data. Without knowing how to keep a stream open over separate read operations, I can see the problem.

Comment: @TylerHundley Yes, I will do it this way if I can't find something more native in Newtonsoft.

Comment: If you want to keep your existing code, you can use `JToken.Load(JsonReader)`. You can create a `JsonTextReader` from a `StreamReader`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. Yes, I am aware of the `streamreader` override. And I will probably go with your suggestion if I end up not finding a native alternative with Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I offer you 3 paths, starting with the least efficient, but with the least code.

**De-serialize into a JObject directly from Stream**

This avoids converting the entire data into string first. Thus saving you the memory space for the string.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    var jobject = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
}
```

**De-serialize into a C# class, then create the class you need. JObject is more heavy weight than POCO, consuming more memory.**

This is straight forward. Suppose that the class you created is `Data`.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    var data = serializer.Deserialize<Data>(jsonReader);
}
```

**Use `JsonTextReader` to directly read into your target data structure**

This involves manually reading the properties and values of your json stream into the structure you need. It saves the memory space of any intermediate objects (or rather, any intermediate objects will contain only the current token you are reading, not the entire data). If you return an `IEnumerable<(IClass1, IClass2)>`, the user of your method can actually process the result in a streaming fashion, making this an [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) algorithm.

I will leave you digging in the documentation to find out how to use it :)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of `JsonTextReader`, but when I checked it out, I decided I am not taking this tedious path. I am too old for this :) I will probably go for option #2, which was also suggested by others in the comments. But your answer is reassuring that I am not missing a better solution.